# Ubuntu 16.04 sleeps / suspend before login screen

Tags: 16.04

On an Ubuntu 16.04 new install with packages upgraded- my laptop (neo b5702n MB40II5 also carried by ctl deltron) sleeps / suspends before it reaches the login screen. On a live cd- it sleeps as well before it reaches the try ubuntu desktop.

Here is my long dmidecode since I am not sure how to attach files

Thanks a lot!

Here is a Pastbin: http://pastebin.com/raw/TqG95Xeu

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmidecode
```

## dmidecode 3.0

```
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.
31 structures occupying 1250 bytes.
Table at 0x000DC010.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
Vendor: Phoenix Technologies LTD
Version: 1.04.01.N
Release Date: 08/10/2011
Address: 0xE68C0
Runtime Size: 104256 bytes
ROM Size: 4096 kB
Characteristics:
    PCI is supported
    PNP is supported
    BIOS is upgradeable
    BIOS shadowing is allowed
    ESCD support is available
    Boot from CD is supported
    ACPI is supported
    USB legacy is supported
    BIOS boot specification is supported
    Targeted content distribution is supported
BIOS Revision: 1.26
Firmware Revision: 1.0

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
Manufacturer: NeoPHL
Product Name: NeoNBK
Version: Not Applicable
Serial Number: 12345678901234567
UUID: 01010101-0101-0101-0101-010101010101
Wake-up Type: Power Switch
SKU Number: 1234567890
Family: Not Specified

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
Manufacturer: NeoPHL
Product Name: NeoNBK
Version: Not Applicable
Serial Number: Not Applicable
Asset Tag: Not Specified
Features: None
Location In Chassis: Not Specified
Chassis Handle: 0xFFFF
Type: Unknown
Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 21 bytes
Chassis Information
Manufacturer: NeoPHL
Type: Laptop
Lock: Not Present
Version: N/A         
Serial Number: 1234567890
Asset Tag: No Asset Tag
Boot-up State: Safe
Power Supply State: Safe
Thermal State: Safe
Security Status: None
OEM Information: 0x00001234
Height: Unspecified
Number Of Power Cords: Unspecified
Contained Elements: 0

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
Socket Designation: CPU
Type: Central Processor
Family: Core i7
Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
ID: A7 06 02 00 FF FB EB BF
Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 42, Stepping 7
Flags:
    FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
    VME (Virtual mode extension)
    DE (Debugging extension)
    PSE (Page size extension)
    TSC (Time stamp counter)
    MSR (Model specific registers)
    PAE (Physical address extension)
    MCE (Machine check exception)
    CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
    APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
    SEP (Fast system call)
    MTRR (Memory type range registers)
    PGE (Page global enable)
    MCA (Machine check architecture)
    CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
    PAT (Page attribute table)
    PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
    CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
    DS (Debug store)
    ACPI (ACPI supported)
    MMX (MMX technology supported)
    FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
    SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
    SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
    SS (Self-snoop)
    HTT (Multi-threading)
    TM (Thermal monitor supported)
    PBE (Pending break enabled)
Version: Not Specified
Voltage: 3.3 V
External Clock: 100 MHz
Max Speed: 2000 MHz
Current Speed: 2000 MHz
Status: Populated, Enabled
Upgrade: Slot 1
L1 Cache Handle: 0x0005
L2 Cache Handle: 0x0006
L3 Cache Handle: 0x0007
Serial Number: Not Specified
Asset Tag: Not Specified
Part Number: Not Specified
Core Count: 4
Core Enabled: 4
Thread Count: 8
Characteristics:
    64-bit capable

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
Socket Designation: L1 Cache
Configuration: Enabled, Socketed, Level 1
Operational Mode: Write Through
Location: Internal
Installed Size: 32 kB
Maximum Size: 32 kB
Supported SRAM Types:
    Burst
    Pipeline Burst
    Asynchronous
Installed SRAM Type: Asynchronous
Speed: Unknown
Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
System Type: Data
Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
Socket Designation: L2 Cache
Configuration: Enabled, Socketed, Level 2
Operational Mode: Write Through
Location: Internal
Installed Size: 256 kB
Maximum Size: 1024 kB
Supported SRAM Types:
    Burst
    Pipeline Burst
    Asynchronous
Installed SRAM Type: Burst
Speed: Unknown
Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
System Type: Unified
Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
Socket Designation: L3 Cache
Configuration: Enabled, Socketed, Level 3
Operational Mode: Write Back
Location: Internal
Installed Size: 6144 kB
Maximum Size: 8192 kB
Supported SRAM Types:
    Burst
    Pipeline Burst
    Asynchronous
Installed SRAM Type: Burst
Speed: Unknown
Error Correction Type: None
System Type: Unified
Associativity: Other

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
Internal Connector Type: None
External Reference Designator: Keyboard
External Connector Type: Circular DIN-8 male
Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
Internal Connector Type: None
External Reference Designator: PS2Mouse
External Connector Type: Circular DIN-8 male
Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
Designation: PEG Slot J5C1
Type: x16 PCI Express x16
Current Usage: Available
Length: Long
ID: 6
Characteristics:
    5.0 V is provided
    3.3 V is provided
Bus Address: 0000:01:00.0

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
Designation: PCI Express Slot J6C2
Type: x1 PCI Express x1
Current Usage: In Use
Length: Long
ID: 7
Characteristics:
    5.0 V is provided
    3.3 V is provided
Bus Address: 0000:02:00.0

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
Type: Video
Status: Enabled
Description: IGD

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
Type: Ethernet
Status: Disabled
Description: GigaLAN

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 15, 29 bytes
System Event Log
Area Length: 16 bytes
Header Start Offset: 0x0000
Header Length: 16 bytes
Data Start Offset: 0x0010
Access Method: General-purpose non-volatile data functions
Access Address: 0x0000
Status: Invalid, Full
Change Token: 0x00000001
Header Format: Type 1
Supported Log Type Descriptors: 3
Descriptor 1: POST error
Data Format 1: POST results bitmap
Descriptor 2: Single-bit ECC memory error
Data Format 2: Multiple-event
Descriptor 3: Multi-bit ECC memory error
Data Format 3: Multiple-event

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
Location: System Board Or Motherboard
Use: System Memory
Error Correction Type: None
Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x000F
Error Information Handle: No Error
Total Width: Unknown
Data Width: Unknown
Size: No Module Installed
Form Factor: SODIMM
Set: 1
Locator: M1
Bank Locator: Bank 0
Type: Unknown
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: Unknown
Manufacturer:                 
Serial Number:                 
Asset Tag:     
Part Number:                   
Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x000F
Error Information Handle: No Error
Total Width: Unknown
Data Width: Unknown
Size: No Module Installed
Form Factor: SODIMM
Set: 1
Locator: M2
Bank Locator: Bank 1
Type: DDR3
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: Unknown
Manufacturer:                 
Serial Number:                 
Asset Tag:     
Part Number:                   
Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x000F
Error Information Handle: No Error
Total Width: 64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: 8192 MB
Form Factor: SODIMM
Set: 1
Locator: M3
Bank Locator: Bank 2
Type: DDR3
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: 1334 MHz
Manufacturer: 0000            
Serial Number: 00000000        
Asset Tag: 0000
Part Number:                   
Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x000F
Error Information Handle: No Error
Total Width: Unknown
Data Width: Unknown
Size: No Module Installed
Form Factor: SODIMM
Set: 1
Locator: M4
Bank Locator: Bank 3
Type: DDR3
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: Unknown
Manufacturer:                 
Serial Number:                 
Asset Tag:     
Part Number:                   
Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
Type: OK
Granularity: Unknown
Operation: Unknown
Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
Memory Array Address: Unknown
Device Address: Unknown
Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
Type: OK
Granularity: Unknown
Operation: Unknown
Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
Memory Array Address: Unknown
Device Address: Unknown
Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
Starting Address: 0x00000000000
Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
Range Size: 8 GB
Physical Array Handle: 0x000F
Partition Width: 2

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
Starting Address: 0x00000000000
Ending Address: 0x000000003FF
Range Size: 1 kB
Physical Device Handle: 0x0010
Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0016
Partition Row Position: Unknown
Interleave Position: Unknown
Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
Starting Address: 0x00000000000
Ending Address: 0x000000003FF
Range Size: 1 kB
Physical Device Handle: 0x0011
Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0016
Partition Row Position: Unknown
Interleave Position: Unknown
Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 23, 13 bytes
System Reset
Status: Enabled
Watchdog Timer: Present
Boot Option: Do Not Reboot
Boot Option On Limit: Do Not Reboot
Reset Count: Unknown
Reset Limit: Unknown
Timer Interval: Unknown
Timeout: Unknown

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 129, 8 bytes
OEM-specific Type
Header and Data:
    81 08 1B 00 01 01 02 01
Strings:
    Intel_ASF
    Intel_ASF_001

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 136, 6 bytes
OEM-specific Type
Header and Data:
    88 06 1C 00 FF FF

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 150, 14 bytes
OEM-specific Type
Header and Data:
    96 0E 1D 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Strings:
    ABSOLUTE(PHOENIX) CLM

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```