# Sleep/Suspend on boot, logout, and switch to terminal after upgrade to 16.04 (Lubuntu)

Tags: boot, 16.04, suspend, logout

I have a combination of errors reported elsewhere such as this [logout problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802311/ubuntu-16-04-logout-cause-the-pc-to-suspend-sleep) and this [boot problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794055/ubuntu-16-04-sleeps-suspend-before-login-screen). Only that in my case it happens twice upon boot. First time after thermal daemon has started, the second just before or at the logon screen. It is not the `thermald` service though, as stopping it does not change the logout behaviour. Moreover, the computer goes to sleep every time I switch to a terminal, i.e. press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Never happened on 14.04., witnessed something similar on a test installation of arch, though.
Hardware is quite old. It is an Cebop Hel500 from 2005. That is based on a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo, so basically the hardware is all Intel. 
I already tried to change the display manager (to `slim`), and I removed `light-lock`...in vain.

Unfortunately, this behaviour renders the use of 16.04. very unconfortable. Any ideas what causes this and - even more important - how to stop it?

....why-o-why did I upgrade...never change a running system!

**Further information**
Checking some log files revealed
in syslog

```
Aug 11 07:55:11 xyz kernel: [    0.100063] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S1_] (20150930/hwxface-580)
Aug 11 07:55:11 xyz kernel: [    0.100077] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20150930/hwxface-580)
```

Something [known](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1485223)?

later I find this block:

```
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd[1]: Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start NTP daemon.
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz ntpdate[2148]: no servers can be used, exiting
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd-sleep[2141]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz ModemManager[1996]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.4.12) starting in system bus...
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start NTP daemon...
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd-sleep[2142]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd-sleep[2141]: Suspending system...
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz systemd[1]: Started IIO Sensor Proxy service.
Aug 11 07:55:12 xyz ntp[2184]:  * Starting NTP server ntpd
Aug 11 07:55:13 xyz dbus[2010]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkitd.service'
Aug 11 07:55:13 xyz systemd[1]: Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
Aug 11 07:55:13 xyz systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service.
Aug 11 07:55:13 xyz thermald[1955]: NO RAPL sysfs present
Aug 11 07:55:13 xyz thermald[1955]: 2 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:d:8 (6:13:8)
Aug 11 07:55:13 xyz thermald[1955]:  Need Linux PowerCap sysfs
Aug 11 07:55:13 xyz apport[1979]:    ...done.
```

some stuff in between and later on a block like:

```
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz dnsmasq[2445]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz dnsmasq[2445]: using nameserver fe80::1%eth3#53
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.6861] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.7868] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz dnsmasq[2445]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.8120] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz ntpd[2864]: Soliciting pool server 144.76.96.7
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz ntpd[2864]: Soliciting pool server 46.4.88.180
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz ntpd[2864]: Soliciting pool server 129.70.132.36
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz ntpd[2864]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Aug 11 07:55:46 xyz nm-dispatcher: req:4 'down' [eth3]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug 11 07:55:46 xyz nm-dispatcher: req:4 'down' [eth3]: start running ordered scripts...
Aug 11 07:55:46 xyz systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 11 07:55:46 xyz systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 11 07:55:46 xyz systemd-sleep[3039]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Aug 11 07:55:46 xyz systemd-sleep[3042]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Aug 11 07:55:46 xyz systemd-sleep[3039]: Suspending system...
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   69.728623] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.380778] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.380884] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.383421] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.384585] PM: Suspending system (mem)
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.384604] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.430782] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.431005] eth3: Going into suspend...
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.544302] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.660023] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1275.120 msecs
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.676023] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.992 msecs
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.676341] r8169 0000:01:0c.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692041] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 16.036 msecs
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692239] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692414] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692415] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] ACPI : EC: EC started
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] Force enabled HPET at resume
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
```

The kernel.log has an according block like:

```
Aug 11 07:55:33 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894933.8160] dhcp6 (eth3): client pid 2545 exited with status 0
Aug 11 07:55:33 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894933.8182] dhcp6 (eth3): state changed bound -> done
Aug 11 07:55:33 xyz kernel: [   56.556134] vboxdrv: Found 1 processor cores
Aug 11 07:55:34 xyz kernel: [   56.816117] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Synchronous, tentative frequency 800059759 Hz
Aug 11 07:55:34 xyz kernel: [   56.816121] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.0.24_Ubuntu (interface 0x00240000)
Aug 11 07:55:34 xyz kernel: [   56.856075] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
Aug 11 07:55:34 xyz kernel: [   56.888112] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
Aug 11 07:55:34 xyz kernel: [   56.944327] VBoxPciLinuxInit
Aug 11 07:55:34 xyz kernel: [   56.980240] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.6526] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.6535] manager: sleeping...
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.6543] device (eth3): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.6562] dhcp4 (eth3): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2421
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.6570] dhcp4 (eth3): state changed bound -> done
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.6587] dhcp6 (eth3): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.6861] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.7868] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 11 07:55:45 xyz NetworkManager[2059]: <info>  [1470894945.8120] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   69.728623] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.380778] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.380884] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.383421] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.384585] PM: Suspending system (mem)
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.384604] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.430782] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.431005] eth3: Going into suspend...
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   70.544302] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.660023] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1275.120 msecs
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.676023] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.992 msecs
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.676341] r8169 0000:01:0c.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692041] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 16.036 msecs
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692239] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692414] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692415] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Aug 11 07:55:52 schwuppdi kernel: [   71.692538] ACPI : EC: EC started
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] Force enabled HPET at resume
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.692538] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.716315] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 16.573 msecs
Aug 11 07:55:52 xyz kernel: [   71.716515] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.439 msecs
```

The boot.log does not show any info about suspend or sleep.

An **important point** is that the sleep also take place if I start the computer with a debian jessie live stick. So I guess that it is a more fundamental problem not exclusively but including Ubuntu.

**Even more info:** I thought it might be a kernel problem, while Lubuntu has the 4.4, the debian live (lxde) has 3.16. Such has the Bunsenlabs Hydrogen, but there I do not witness the suspend.

**Wrong:** Bunsenlabs has the suspend problem, but not on login. A test installation shows it on logout and upon changing to tty1,2,3,etc, i.e. Crtl+Alt+F1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

After checking once again the error messages including the dump of `dmesg > dmesg.txt` after boot, I found a [discussion for Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=186448). After trying both options idependently it turns out that adding `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` did the trick. The also mentioned `HandleSuspendKey=ignore` was not necessary, though. Honestly, I consider this more a workaround than a solution. While the present problem is solved, hence, it remains unclear to me what actually changed from 14.04 to 16.04 to make it appear in the first place.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, your tip did the trick for another rare Amilor Pro :)

Comment: @alex Glad to hear that it helped someone.